# How to display show replies button for the comment which has replies?

Tags: php, function, filter

I am creating nested comment system with reply. comments goes longer and longer in page that is why I wanted to toggle replies.

I already do that auto adding class margins etc.

I have problem with displaying button, **show replies** button displays under all comments which has parent-id 0, even if it doesn't have the replies.

because of this :

```
if($parent_id == 0){
    $marginleft = 0;
    $adclass = "parent";
    $adbtn = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs show_reply">show replies</button>';
}else{
    $marginleft = $marginleft + 15;
    $adclass = "child";
    $adbtn = "";
}
```

Which is working correct way for the class and margin etc.

Here is the php code :

```
$post_id = intval($_POST["comment_post_id"]);
$parent = intval('0');
$active = 'Y';

$sth = $pdo->prepare(
    "SELECT * FROM comments
        JOIN profiles ON comments.com_uid = profiles.ik_uid
        WHERE comments.comment_post_id = ? 
        AND comments.comment_parent_id = ? 
        AND comments.active = ? ORDER BY comment_id DESC
    ");
$sth->execute([$post_id, $parent, $active]);
$count = $sth->rowCount();

$output = '';
if($count > 0){
    while($row = $sth->fetch()){
        if($row['ik_img'] !== ''){
            $image = explode('.',$row['ik_img']);
            $ik_img = $image[0].".webp";
            $ik = $row['ik_img'];
        }else{
            $ik_img = 'avatar.jpg';
            $ik = 'avatar.jpg';
        }
        if($row['comment_parent_id'] !== $row['comment_id']){
            $adclass = "parent";
            $adbtn = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs show_reply">show replies</button>';
        }else{
            $adclass = "child";
            $adbtn = "";
        }
        $output .= '
            <div class="form-group border-bottom '.$adclass.'">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12"><b>'.htmlspecialchars(ucfirst($row["comment_sender_name"])).'</b> said!</div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-2 stimg">
                            <picture>
                                <source type="image/webp" srcset="uploads/small/'.$ik_img.'">
                                <img src="uploads/small/'.$ik.'" alt="'.htmlspecialchars($row['comment_sender_name']).'" class="img-fluid">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-10 sttext">'.htmlspecialchars($row['comment']).'</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 sttime">'.htmlspecialchars($row["comment_date"]).'
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs reply" id="'.intval($row["comment_id"]).'">Reply <i class="fas fa-share"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">'.$adbtn.'</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ';
        $output .= get_comments($pdo, intval($row["comment_id"]), intval($row["comment_post_id"]));
    }
}

echo $output;

function get_comments($pdo, $parent_id = 0,$post_id, $active = 'Y', $marginleft = 0){
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare(
            "SELECT * FROM comments
            JOIN profiles ON comments.com_uid = profiles.ik_uid
            WHERE comments.comment_post_id = ? 
            AND comments.comment_parent_id = ? 
            AND comments.active = ? ORDER BY comment_id DESC
        ");
    $stmt->execute([$post_id, $parent_id, $active]);
    $count = $stmt->rowCount();
    $output = '';
    if($count > 0){
        if($parent_id == 0){
            $marginleft = 0;
            $adclass = "parent";
            $adbtn = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs show_reply">show replies</button>';
        }else{
            $marginleft = $marginleft + 15;
            $adclass = "child";
            $adbtn = "";
        }
        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        if($row['ik_img'] !== ''){
            $image = explode('.',$row['ik_img']);
            $ik_img = $image[0].".webp";
            $ik = $row['ik_img'];
        }else{
            $ik_img = 'avatar.jpg';
            $ik = 'avatar.jpg';
        }
        $output .= '
            <div class="form-group border-bottom '.$adclass.'" style="padding-left:'.$marginleft.'px;">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12"><b>'.htmlspecialchars(ucfirst($row["comment_sender_name"])).'</b> said!</div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-2 stimg">
                            <picture>
                            <source srcset="uploads/small/'.$ik_img.'" type="image/webp">
                            <img src="uploads/small/'.$ik.'" alt="'.htmlspecialchars($row['comment_sender_name']).'" class="img-fluid">
                            </picture>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-10 sttext">'.htmlspecialchars($row['comment']).'</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 sttime">'.htmlspecialchars($row["comment_date"]).'
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs reply" id="'.intval($row["comment_id"]).'">Reply <i class="fas fa-share"></i></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12">'.$adbtn.'</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ';
        $output .= get_comments($pdo, intval($row["comment_id"]), $marginleft);
        }
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Database setup :
[image]

**Solved I used multilevel recursive function (Like a multilevel menu) it works fine.**

Comment: "I need a function which can do more" and "correct way" doesn't tell us much. Tell us what inputs you have and what outputs you expect. Also, it is very rare that people asking for what you are asking for, actually want that. I'm not saying that this is your case, but it is rare. You are using prepared statements which is great. Other than that, the general rule is to avoiding escaping until you actually need to (basically, on render).

Comment: @ChrisHaas As I said in question I needed a function which can do more than (convert double quotes or single quotes), so I've created a function which can (convert quotes, slashes, spaces etc.) I need to know if my functions are created correctly.I will edit and try to explain beter. Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately we still really can't tell you if they are correct because we really need a set of inputs mapped to a set of expected outputs. For instance, what do you want `'A\\\B'` to map to? And what about `A\"\B`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all I've saw few mistakes in your code**:

- Your code makes too many requests to your database - for each comment you will make a new request your database to get it's sub comments - soon this will cause slow load speed of your pages
- Your database structure doesn't use indexes - with many records this will cause slow requests to this table
- Your html code is not good

**Database structure for my example**:

```
CREATE TABLE `comments` (
    `comment_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `com_uid` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `comment_parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `comment_post_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `comment` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
    `comment_sender_name` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
    `active` enum('Y','N') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y',
    `comment_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`),
    KEY `com_uid` (`com_uid`),
    KEY `comment_parent_id` (`comment_parent_id`),
    KEY `comment_post_id` (`comment_post_id`),
    KEY `active` (`active`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**PHP Code to generate the html**:

```
$query = '
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        comments
    LEFT JOIN
        profiles ON (comments.com_uid = profiles.ik_uid)
    WHERE
        comments.comment_post_id = :post_id AND
        comments.active = :active
    ORDER BY
        comment_date ASC
';
$statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
$statement->execute([':post_id' => $post_id, ':active' => 'Y']);
$count = $statement->rowCount();

$comments = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$comments = buildNestedComments($comments);
$html = getCommentsHtml($comments);

function getArrayWithKeys($array, $key)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        $result[$value[$key]] = $value;
    }
    
    return $result;
}

function buildNestedComments($comments)
{
    $comments = getArrayWithKeys($comments, 'comment_id');
    
    $nestedComments = [];
    foreach ($comments as &$comment) {
        $parentId = (isset($comment['comment_parent_id']) && !empty($comment['comment_parent_id'])) ? (int)$comment['comment_parent_id'] : null;
        if ($parentId === null) {
            $nestedComments[] = &$comment;
            if (!isset($comment['comments'])) {
                $comment['count'] = 0;
                $comment['comments'] = [];
            }
        } else {
            if (isset($comments[$parentId])) {
                if (!isset($comments[$parentId]['comments'])) {
                    $comments[$parentId]['count'] = 0;
                    $comments[$parentId]['comments'] = [];
                }
                
                $comments[$parentId]['count']++;
                $comments[$parentId]['comments'][] = &$comment;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return $nestedComments;
}

function getCommentsHtml($comments)
{
    $html = '';
    foreach ($comments as $comment) {
        if (
            isset($comment['ik_img']) &&
            !empty($comment['ik_img'])
        ) {
            $image = explode('.',$comment['ik_img']);
            $ik_img = $image[0] . '.webp';
            $ik = $comment['ik_img'];
        } else {
            $ik_img = 'avatar.jpg';
            $ik = 'avatar.jpg';
        }
        
        $class = (isset($comment['comment_parent_id']) && !empty($comment['comment_parent_id'])) ? 'comment-' . $comment['comment_id'] . ' comment-parent-' . $comment['comment_parent_id'] : 'comment-' . $comment['comment_id'];
        
        $button = '';
        $subCommentsHtml = '';
        if (
            isset($comment['comments']) &&
            !empty($comment['comments'])
        ) {
            $button = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs show_reply">show replies</button>';
            $subCommentsHtml = getCommentsHtml($comment['comments']);
        }
        
        $html .= '<div class="form-group border-bottom '.$class.'">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12"><b>' . htmlspecialchars(ucfirst($comment["comment_sender_name"])) . '</b> said!</div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-2 stimg">
                        <picture>
                            <source type="image/webp" srcset="uploads/small/' . $ik_img . '">
                            <img src="uploads/small/' . $ik . '" alt="'.htmlspecialchars($comment['comment_sender_name']).'" class="img-fluid">
                        </picture>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-10 sttext">' . htmlspecialchars($comment['comment']) . '</div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 sttime">' . htmlspecialchars($comment["comment_date"]) . '
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs reply" id="' . intval($comment["comment_id"]) . '">Reply <i class="fas fa-share"></i></button>
                </div>
                <div class="col-12">' . $button . '</div>
                <div class="sub-comments">' . $subCommentsHtml . '</div>
            </div>
        </div>';
    }
    
    return $html;
}
```

As you can see in my example I'm getting all comments at once and after that I've made few things:

- Getting the comments as associative array with `comment_id` as key in `getArrayWithKeys` function
- Getting a nested associative array with parent comments and all of their sub comments are in `comments` key of the array in `buildNestedComments` function
- Getting the html for all of these comments where sub comments are nested in div with class `sub-comments` for easier management with javascript

Then you will be able to use a little css and javascript to style this html and to show/hide sub comments.

**Also you have to think about few points**:

- Amount of comments - if there are a lot of comments maybe it will be better to load first 10-20 comments
- Lazy load of comments - first load all parent comments and then load their sub comments

Comment: Thanks for the effort what is output of the function ? `buildNestedComments();` ?

Comment: The same as from database but it adds sub comments and their count to comments parent comments

Comment: it doesnt display comments, just a blank page on both ways with calling function like this `buildNestedComments(0);` or load with ajax load function (mine works with load function ajax). now I get this error `[03-Jan-2021 23:34:04 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  Undefined array key "comment_post_id" in D:\xampp\htdocs\html\modules\load_comment.php on line 23
[03-Jan-2021 23:34:04 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  foreach() argument must be of type array|object, int given in D:\xampp\htdocs\html\modules\load_comment.php on line 49

`

Comment: What is your php version? Any errors in log?

Comment: both php8 - mysql-8 the problem is in `foreach ($array as $value) {`

Comment: Do you solve the issue? Or it keeps working on my side only?

Comment: nope it doesnt work properly, not nested and to complex. and my main problem is displaying button on comment if it has replies.

Comment: You cannot do that with you code because at this state. You have to create add a subquery to count sub comments as Zoran said or you have to fetch all comments as in my example. Currently your code first gets all top level comments and after that loads sub comments. If you wish Im in discussion room and available for chat to help you :)

Comment: I didnt use your codes because of html structer is not what I expect, but I got ideas from your answer, indexes/relationships and most importand part was creating dynamic parent class on a child coment. and I created my own class this one https://stackoverflow.com/q/65635498/12232340 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You said,

```
"I have problem with displaying button, show replies button displays under all 
comments which has parent-id 0, even if it doesn't have the replies.".
```

I think you can achiave it with sql query - you can calculate column **replies_count** with **sub query**. With that info you can modifie php code to draw
**Show replies (replies_count)** btn if they exist.

This would be a query:

```
SELECT *,
        (
            select count(*)
            from comments cc
            where cc.comment_parent_id = c.id

        ) replies_count

FROM comments c
JOIN profiles ON c.com_uid = profiles.ik_uid
WHERE c.comment_post_id = ? 
AND c.comment_parent_id = ? 
AND c.active = ? ORDER BY comment_id DESC
```

And then, in PHP you just use it like this:

```
if( $row['replies_count']  > 0 ) {

    // draw btn
}
```

Comment: I tried array simmiler to that like so `$MultiComments['parent_comments'][$row['comment_parent_id']][] = $row['comment_id']; ` and in function `foreach ($comment['parent_comments'][$parent] as $comment_id) {
            if (isset($comment['parent_comments'][$comment_id])) { // draw btn
}` couldnt make it work. let me try your solution.

Comment: This answer returns comments only if comment has a reply.

Comment: I'm 98% sure you will fix your problem with this idea (using subquery). You should add this subquery in every query that you use for fetching comments (in get_comments function and in first query outside function). Your logic is to get comments with function and in that momment you don't know if that comment has replies, unless you use subquery to count them. With that info, you can evan improve code to not call get_comments funtion if $row['replies_count'] == 0. I will be online today, fill free to reply to this comment so we can work it out. I don't have reputation to comment elsewere.

Comment: GTsvetanov gave you few great advices for optimization and user experience. I will just add one more idea to his idea. Simplest solution with good ux and user experience, would be to load top level comments comments (parent_id is null) and call subquery as in my exapmle. Then if $row['replies_count']  > 0 you draw btn that will load replies with ajax. As GTsvetanov said, this will make your code run faster and you would allow user  to chose what he wants to look. But first, i would suggest you focus on your current code to make it work, becouse you are so close. And then improve it if you want

Comment: Hi Zoran, I changed my function to a recursive (like a multilevel menu) function and it works fine. Thanks for the effort.